# How can I make the profile and logout link to be shown when the user is logged in?

Tags: angular, authentication, routes

I've tried various ways like editing the layout.component.ts file but still I feel like I'm missing something

Here is the code for layout.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg custom-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="home">
        <img src="assets\images\Black & White Minimalist Business Logo.png" alt="MS logo" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top me-2">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="login">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="register">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="profile">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="logout">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>    
  </nav>
  <!-- Add a placeholder for the child components -->
  <ng-content></ng-content>
```

Here is the file for layout.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
  }
  
}
```

Here is the code for auth.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return localStorage.getItem('authToken') !== null;
  }
  
}
```

Here is the login.component.html

```
<div class="login-box"> 
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h1 class="header">Welcome to MS</h1>
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
        account_circle
        </span> 
      <label for="inputUsername" class="visually-hidden">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
        key
        </span>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="visually-hidden">Password</label>
      <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-login">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
      <br>
        <label class="createacc" for="terms"> OR <a routerLink="/register">Create an Account</a> on MS website </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the login.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  username!: string;
  password!: string;
  
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  
  onSubmit() {
    // Call the login method when the form is submitted
    this.login();
  }

  login() {
    // Retrieve user data from local storage
    const userDataString = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (userDataString) {
      const userData = JSON.parse(userDataString);
      console.log('Username:', userData.username);
      console.log('Email:', userData.email);
      console.log('Password:', userData.password);

      // Check if the entered username and password match the stored user data
      if (this.username === userData.username && this.password === userData.password) {
        console.log('Login successful');
        // Redirect to the movie schedule page
        this.router.navigate(['/movie-schedule']);
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid username or password');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('User data not found in local storage');
    }
  }
}
```

**The only thing I want to happen is for the logout and signup link to be removed when the user is logged in then the profile and logout would be the one showed up when the user is logged in**

Here it is when the user is not logged in
[image]

Here it is when logged in
[image]

Also note that the layout component is being wrapped in all the other components here is the code for app.component.html

```
<app-layout>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running change detection manually after login?

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef){}

this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Comment: haven't tried to do so. How would that be?